# Windows Servers Deny Remote Creditials

Tags: group-policy, windows-authentication

Here's the layout:

-Four domain controllers(2003 & 2008)

-Windows Servers (2003 & 2008)

-The PDC is Windows 2008 and there are some GPOs

-All servers ping, no firewalls, no major or much of a minor change since this condition showed up (that I'm aware of)

My IT Dept has reached a point of not knowing what to try next. About six days ago, a Windows 2008 Server(member of the domain) would no longer allow access to shares or RDP to domain users. "Net View \Server-Name" for such domain users would yield "System Error 5: Access Denied". The server was removed and re-joined to the domain. Still same problem. What we did discover, is if the domain user authenticates with the console, and only with the console, all outside remote access shares & RDP would magically be restored. If the server should ever be rebooted, those remote accesses would then be denied until authenticated on the domain at the said server's local console once again. This is happening on multiple servers. If a server gets rebooted, the same situation will now exist when it did not prior to a reboot.

Any clue to what is causing this??

Comment: Without knowing much about your situation or reviewing your event logs, I'd suggest there could be a licensing issue at play here. How many users do you have connecting to these RDP session hosts? If it's more than two you need RDS CALs and an RDS licensing server.

Comment: We're on enterprise level license. Once authenticated through a server console, that server can then support multiple connections.

Comment: From debug\netlogon....


03/17 10:03:17 [LOGON] SamLogon: Network logon of HEALTH\XXXXXX from XXXXXXX Entered


03/17 10:03:17 [LOGON] SamLogon: Network logon of HEALTH\XXXXXX from XXXXXXX Returns 0x0